# how to make every URL open in android app

Tags: android

For my website, I had built an android app just as a wrapper to the website in an android studio.

I have two-buttons on my website,

1. Calling Button: when I click on that it calls will connect to the
   specific customers' mobile.
2. WhatsApp button: when I click on this it will redirect WhatsApp
   application for sending a message that customers.

These two buttons are working fine on the website.

The problem is when I try to use these buttons on the Android app it's not working.

it is showing webpage not available

Comment: So you do it wrong. Please explain how you do it wrong.

Comment: We would need to see how you implemented that functionality for us to figure out where you're going wrong. Some code snippet is required.